# FormView on Object with IEnumerable property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, .net-4.5

Person view model:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Relatives { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `asp:FormView` control on my page which contains an `asp:GridView` which is bound to a collection property on my `Person` class.

```
<asp:FormView ID="ui_frmMain" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit" OnCallingDataMethods="ui_frmMain_CallingDataMethods" SelectMethod="GetItems" UpdateMethod="UpdateItems" ItemType="Person">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <%# Item.Name %>
        <asp:GridView ID="..." runat="server" DataSource='<%# Bind("Relatives") %>' ItemType="Person">
             <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="Selected" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("IsSelected") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
    <EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

I am using .Net 4.5 data binding to send my model back to the UpdateMethod `UpdateItems(Person person)` however the `Relatives` property is always null.

Is there a way to:

- Two way bind from a gridview
- Bind the gridview's CheckBox to the `IsSelected` property on the model

Comment: Could you provide more information?

Comment: I have added some more detail - thanks

Comment: Try to bind to your Person entity in the checkbox with Checked="<%# Item.IsSelected) %>". Or otherwise use Checked="<%# BindItem.IsSelected) %>".

Answer (score 0):

Before you save the changes on the updated person object "manually" loop through and add nested collection objects one by one.

For example:

```
UpdateItems(Person person)
{
   // :( probably null for Relatives :(
   GridView myGrid = (GridView)FindControl("MyGrid");
   for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       Textbox txtName = (Textbox)myGrid.Rows[i].FindControl("");
       CheckBox chkSelected = (Checkbox)myGrid.Rows[i].FindControl("");
       Person p = new Person();
       p.Name = txtName.Text;
       p.IsSelected = chkSelected.cheked;
       person.Relatives.Add(p);
    }
    myEntity.SaveChanges();
```

This method it terrible, but I haven't seen anything that will recognize changes in the nested collection yet.